# How to make a custom Scripts folder?

Tags: command-line, scripts

I have a few scripts, one that launches thinkorswim, one that grabs doppler radar, etc, that I have placed in `/usr/bin` so that every time I open a terminal, and no matter what directory my terminal is in, I can simply type the name of the script and have it run. I was wondering if there is a way to this with another folder, preferably in the home directory. That is, I can have the script in this folder, and run it from anywhere just as if it were in `/usr/bin`.

I don't know if this matters, but I use ZSH as my shell and I use Terminator as my terminal emulator. Also, for the record, I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and i3wm 4.17.1.

Thanks.

Comment: Just add that directory at end of the PATH variable.

Comment: believe the beginning is better, whatever is looking for a cmd will stop at the first match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your scripts into `$HOME/bin` or `$HOME/.local/bin`. These two directories are automatically included in the `$PATH` if they exist.

You could also put your scripts into other directories but then you will need to add them manually into `$PATH`.

Please don't put custom scripts into `/usr` since that directory is designed for the distro's package manager.

Comment: For system wide availability of custom scripts, `/usr/local/bin` would be a suitable location.